# wp_remote_get - Wordpress - No use proxy

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have a cron that uses this command to set the proxy

```
add_action('http_api_curl', array(__CLASS__, 'addProxy'), 10, 3);
```

inside the `addProxy` function there is this

`curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);`

The problem is when within the execution of this function I want to execute an example action

```
    return wp_remote_get(
        $url,
        array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $api_key,
            ),
            'timeout' => self::CURL_TIMEOUT,
        )
    );
```

wp_remote_get runs with the proxy
What I need is for it to run without the proxy

**Is there any command to run wp_remote_get without proxy? (ignore proxy)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such parameter of the `wp_remote_get` to overwrite `http_api_curl` hook added action functions.

To achieve what you want and solve your issue you need to update your cron function and check whether to execute its body in all cases, for example:

```php
class __CLASS__ {

  public function addProxy ( $handle, array $parsed_args, $url ) {
    // You can distinct your wp_remote_get call by specific $url value
    if ( 'https://service.com/auth' === $url ) {
      return;
    }

    // Or... you can distinct by some $parsed_args like headers
    if ( array_key_exists( 'Authorisation,' $parsed_args['headers'] ) ) {
       return;
    }
  
    // the rest of your current addProxy() function body with the curl options...
  ...
}
```

This way you can avoid executing the `addProxy` on certain requests, like

```php
wp_remote_get( 'https://service.com/auth',  array(...), );
```

The above will not trigger the execution of the `addProxy` function body code...

Comment: `add_action(
    'http_api_curl',
    static function ($resource, $request, $url) {
        curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://localhost:7080'); // PROXY details with port
    },
    10,
    3
);`

In any case can I override the use of proxy via curl?
Is there any option to disable CURLOPT_PROXY

Comment: I'm sorry, I understood what you said and I managed to solve it.
Thank you very much!